# How do I fix checking out HEAD^ in git

Tags: git, git-svn

Okay so I made some changes in my project that resulted in a huge mess. I had already committed the changes so I could go back to it later, and then used git checkout HEAD^ to checkout the previous commit. Now as I'm making commits to my project it shows the SHA-1 on the command line as the working branch (instead of master)

I don't know everything there is to know about git but I'm guessing HEAD is still pointing to my broken copy as I'm going off in a tangent and have resolved the problem. How can I point HEAD to the latest commit I'm working from?

I'm guessing it has to do with rebase but I'm not 100% sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*Now as I'm making commits to my project it shows the SHA-1 on the command line as the working branch (instead of master)*

This probably means you have a “detached HEAD”. A detached HEAD points directly to a commit instead of pointing to a branch (which then points to a commit). A detached head is like an unnamed branch.

This state was caused by your `git checkout HEAD^` command as `HEAD^` refers to a commit, not to a branch name. You probably wanted to do `git reset --hard HEAD^`—**while *master* was still the active branch**—to drop the most recent commit from *master* (it would still exist on disk and be reachable through the reflog until its entry in the reflog expired).

*How can I point HEAD to the latest commit I'm working from?*

`HEAD` is always the commit from which you are working, whether it is detached or not.

If you mean “How can I point *master* to the latest commit I'm working from?”, then that is the same as asking “How can I get *master* to point to `HEAD`?”. The answer is

```
git branch -f master HEAD
```

(actually, you can leave off `HEAD`, since it is the default). This forcibly resets *master* to the commit currently at `HEAD`. Any commits on *master* that are not reachable via  another branch or the current `HEAD` will henceforth only be reachable via the reflog and will eventually be garbage collected (this throws away, from *master*, anything in *master* that is not in `HEAD`). You also probably want to reattach your `HEAD` to this updated master after this.

```
git checkout master
```

Instead of the two commands above, you could reattach `HEAD` first, then reset *master* with these two consecutive commands:

```
git checkout master         # reattach, commit at HEAD is now the unwanted commit
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}   # reset master to the commit at HEAD before the prior command
```

The `HEAD@{1}` notation is used to access entries in the reflog. This example just means “the previous `HEAD`” (i.e. “the commit at `HEAD` before the most recent operation that affected `HEAD`”).

Answer (score 3):

```
git checkout HEAD
git reset HEAD^
```

This will erase the most recent commit.  Confirm that it worked with `svn log`.

I noticed you tagged this git-svn. This will only work if you haven't pushed the messed up commit out to svn yet.  If you have, you'll need to apply a reverse merge of the messed up commit like this:

```
$ git log
commit 30480f327040f812cb2afffdd1cdd374bf26fe83
Author: you
Date: today

    messed up commit

$ git revert 30480f327040f812cb2afffdd1cdd374bf26fe83
```

where 30480f327040f812cb2afffdd1cdd374bf26fe83 is the hash of the messed up commit.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is [`git reset`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset):

```
git checkout HEAD
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

This will take "master" back to one revision prior to the current HEAD. What you're working with at the moment is called a "detached head", since it doesn't have a symbolic name associated with it.